# Postgres PSQL displays invalid chars in windows cmd

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using windows 10 - and when I run PSQL from the cmd I'm getting invalid chars:
[image]

My guess is that it's trying to write Hebrew to the command line.

In regional settings of my windows 10 - the Location is set to "United States" the Formats are set to "Hebrew Israel" and the default language for non unicode applications is set to "Hebrew Israel"

How do I get postgres to play nice with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions from the [`psql` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.12), translated to Hebrew.

Before starting `psql`,

- set the font to “Lucida Console”
- change the encoding with `chcp 1255`.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way for me to force psql to speak english in the console? I want all the messages and error messages to be in english so I'll be able to goggle them.

Comment: I don't have Windows, but since PostgreSQL is using gettext, you could try setting the environment variable `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: postgresql default language is set in postgresql.conf  ("/program files/postgres/" somewhere)

Comment: @Jasen Not for the messages written by the `psql` executable.